Proving that: $\left( \sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca} \right) \cdot (ab + bc + ca) \leq \sqrt{2}$
Problem:
Let $(a, b, c)$ be positive real numbers satisfying $a + b + c = 1$. Prove that:
$$\left( \sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca} \right) \cdot (ab + bc + ca) \leq \sqrt{2}$$
My Work
To prove the inequality, i started by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz.
$$(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2)(y_1^2 + y_2^2 + \ldots + y_n^2) \geq (x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 + \ldots + x_n y_n)^2$$
In my case, I set
$x_1 = \sqrt{ab},\:x_2 = \sqrt{bc}, \: x_3 = \sqrt{ca}$ and $y_1 = 1, \:y_2 = 1, \:y_3 = 1$. Applying Cauchy-Schwarz, I got:
$$(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca})^2 \leq (1 + 1 + 1)(ab + bc + ca)$$
This simplifies to:
$$(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca})^2 \leq 3(ab + bc + ca)$$
Taking the square root of both sides yields:
$$\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca} \leq \sqrt{3(ab + bc + ca)}$$
Next, i substituted this result into the original expression. Our goal is to show:
$$\left( \sqrt{3(ab + bc + ca)} \right) \cdot (ab + bc + ca) \leq \sqrt{2}$$
Let us denote: $x = ab + bc + ca$. Thus, we want to prove:
$$\sqrt{3x} \cdot x \leq \sqrt{2}$$
Squaring both sides yields:
$$3x^2 \leq 2$$
Thus, we must show:
$$x^2 \leq \frac{2}{3}$$
I don't know how to proceed further, It doesn't seem I am getting somewhere. Can anyone please help to complete the proof

Squaring both sides in the second-to-last step results in $3x^3\leq 2.$

To finish your work:
From $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$ one gets $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$
Then:
$$1 = (a+b+c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)\ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$$
$$x=ab+bc+ca\le\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\sqrt{3x}\cdot x\le 1\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3} \text{ much less than }\sqrt{2}$$
Equality takes place when $a=b=c=\frac{1}{3}$
Also, for the C-S part you can simply use AM-QM inequality.

By rearrangement inequality
$$\left( \sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca} \right) \cdot (ab + bc + ca) \le ab + bc + ca=\frac{1-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}2\le \frac13\le \sqrt 2$$
indeed by AM-QM $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge \frac13$.

We have
$$
2(ab+ac+bc)< 2ab+2ac+2bc+a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2=1,
$$
hence $ab+ac+bc<\frac{1}{2}$. What can we say about the first factor
$\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}$?
Following your computation,
$$
\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca} \leq \sqrt{3(ab + bc + ca)}<\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}.
$$
Hence we have
$$
\left( \sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca} \right) \cdot (ab + bc + ca) <\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}.
$$
This is much smaller than $\sqrt{2}$.

It is not wrong. It just does not use the smallest possible upper bound, but a different one. By the way, $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}$ is probably not the smallest one, either.

@CircuitSage What is the source of your question?

It's from the Chinese mathematics Olympiad (CMO) 2006

So it should be in here?

@DietrichBurde I don't think CMO would ask students to prove such a loose bound

@Momo Therefore I have asked for the source, to check myself for typos. It seems likely that the original question is different.

You are right actually but in the book which I was solving it is written Chinese MO 2006 but it is actually a modified version of  question number 2 Chinese team selection test (TST) 2006 the original question is as follows given three positive real numbers (x,y,z) such that x+y+z = 1
Prove that $\dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{xy + yz}} + \dfrac{yz}{\sqrt{yz + zx}} + \dfrac{zx}{\sqrt{zx + xy}} \leq \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

